# WSO2 Eclipse plugin not working well

Tags: eclipse, maven, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using:

- Eclipse Kepler
- WSO2 Developer Studio v3.2 plugin
- WSO2 esb v4.7.0
- Maven 3.x
- Java 1.7.x
- Windows 7

And I'm having the following problems in Eclipse when using WSO2 Development Studio:

- if I try to edit a file (via Design or Source view), the changes are not saved and are reverted back to the original values.
- when I add a new Registry Resource to my Registry project, this resource is not added to the carbon file.
- by deleting a resource file, the resource still exists in the project/Registry(path) and is not cleaned up well. I have to delete it manually from artifact.xml.
- when I try to make a carbon file by running 'mvn clean install' from the command line, the build hangs. I've fixed this by changing the version of 'maven-car-plugin, wso2-esb-proxy-plugin, wso2-general-project-plugin' to 2.0.5 (default: 2.0.4).

And changes made to pom files are also not saved, they always revert back to original values.

Are these problems known and is there any solution available ?

Thx in advance and looking forward for a reply.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I need to emphasize that WSO2 Dev Studio 3.2.0 is not tested and verified with Eclipse Kepler and the officially supported Eclipse version is Eclipse Juno SR2. Even-though Kepler is not tested, I do expect most of the features to work.

Following are the answers for your comments/questions:

Q.if I try to edit a file (via Design or Source view), the changes are
   not saved and are reverted back to the original values.

Ans: What is the file you are referring here? Is it an artifact file? or an utility file such as pom.xml?

We have not come across this issue before that values are being reverted back to previous. However there is a known behavior that if you try to add a new element/value that is not being recognized by the ESB Editor, it will simply drop the newly added value from the source.But that behavior is specific to ESB Graphical Editor. Without knowing the type of file you are referring, I cannot 100% be sure what is going on.

Q. when I add a new Registry Resource to my Registry project, this
   resource is not added to the carbon file.

Ans: Yes, That is the expected behavior. Rationale is that, In a given workspace there can be multiple C-App Projects existing at the same time. So we are not sure to which C-App project user wishes to include a given registry Resource. Adding the same registry resource or any other artifact to all the C-App projects does not seem right. Therefore we do not automatically include a Registry Resource or any other artifact in to C-App projects.

Another special scenario with Registry Resources is that, you can deploy a Registry Resource to any Carbon Server. Therefore we cannot 100% be sure about the correct Server Role for the Registry Resource.

After considering all the above facts we have decided not to include any artifact in to C-App Project and let users to add them.

Q. by deleting a resource file, the resource still exists in the
   project/Registry(path) and is not cleaned up well. I have to delete
   it manually from artifact.xml.

Ans: This could be due to a bug in the Refactoring component in Dev Studio. However we have done some modifications to the refactor components to improve it and fix some bugs in it for Developer Studio 3.3.0 Alpha 3 version. With those fixes, most of such issues will go away.

Q. when I try to make a carbon file by running 'mvn clean install' from
   the command line, the build hangs. I've fixed this by changing the
   version of 'maven-car-plugin, wso2-esb-proxy-plugin,
   wso2-general-project-plugin' to 2.0.5 (default: 2.0.4).

Ans: There was serious a performance issue related to wso2-general-project-plugin and wso2 esb artifact plugins released with Developer Studio 3.2.0. We have identified this issue [[1]](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-2043) and fixed in the latest versions of the plugins as you have discovered. So with those plugins, you will experience a greater performance improvements.

Q. changes made to pom files are also not saved, they always revert back to original values.

Ans: There is a known issue with updating properties section of the pom.xml of C-App project [[2]](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-2027) and we are working on fixing this for the upcoming Dev Studio release.

Hope this clarifies some of the concerns you have and provide answers to your queries.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana